# Take input from the userspace in the kernel

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel

I'm new to kernel programming and I was making changes in the memory module. The issue is that when I put in `printk()` statements, at the boot the output is extremely verbose and because the prints are computationally expensive it takes a lot of time to boot. I was thinking of building a toggle for it as when it boots it can ask the user to switch the prints on/off.

I have seen the `sscanf()` or `vsscanf()` but that takes input only from the already given string. I also know that it should not be logically allowed to take input like this for the matters of safety but would there be a way to make sure that can be done? Or any other approach that I'm not aware of?

Edit : For clarity what I mean to do is : turning the prints on/off on demand after the kernel is booting/booted.

Comment: `dmesg` may be helpful for you to understand `printk` output.

Comment: Generally kernel parameters are modified at runtime through ad-hoc "files" in sysfs or procfs.

Comment: sysfs is surely an interesting approach but my question still stands on how would I edit any of the attributes with a keyboard interrupt or similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to configure the behavior of the kernel before it boots, you have two easy ways:

- Since this is a debugging problem, the easiest and less intrusive option is to configure two kernels (one enabled, one disabled), and let the user select which one to boot in e.g. GRUB.
- If you really need to use the very same kernel (e.g. some users may need it at some moment and you don't want or can't distribute several versions), then use a boot kernel parameter. Take a look at the macros and documentation at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.17/source/include/linux/moduleparam.h

Of course, there may be other ways to take input available for you (i.e. from any kind of persistent storage) -- but for debugging purposes, I would suggest going for the first option.

Comment: I suspect he'd like to switch his prints on once the kernel has booted, so not on the start, but on demand while the kernel is running.

Comment: @MatteoItalia: It seems to me that OP was referring to boot time: "*at the boot the output is extremely verbose and because the prints are computationally expensive it takes a lot of time to boot.*", no? Otherwise, of course, there are many other ways to configure anything in the kernel.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replies. but I was really asking for on demand while the kernel is running.
@Acron yes the first approach you specified is exactly what I am doing but switching kernels after constant edits-compiles-runs eats up a lot of time but at the same time debugging is important and hence this question.

Comment: @PratikSampat: Alright, then @MatteoItalia was right :-) Maybe emphasize it in the question as well. As for the actual question, in this case, and as Matteo pointed out, you can use `sysfs`.